# Switch case statement from an array

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I am trying to use a switch statement with how many times each statement is used. so far I am having an issue with consecutive statements must be separated with ";" I have checking into the error and so far all I have been able to locate is that there is an issue with closed brackets but all of my brackets appear to be closed.

```
func switchInt() -> Array<Int> {

    var switchAr = [Int] ()
    var lowSwitch = 0
    var medSwitch = 0
    var highSwitch = 0

    for _ in 1...10 {

        let switchInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))

        switch switchInt {

        case 0...35:
            return lowSwitch +=1
            switchAr.append(switchInt)
        case switchAr 35<=67:
            medSwitch +=1
            switchAr.append(switchInt)
        case switchAr 70<=100:
            highSwitch; +=1
            switchAr.append(switchInt)

        default:
            print("does not compute")
        }

    }

    return(switchAr)
}
```

Comment: You got the first case almost correct and after that it's a big mess.

Comment: `highSwitch; +=1` Change to `highSwitch += 1`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At least this compiles, but I'm not sure what do you want to do with that:

```
func switchInt() -> Array<Int> {

    var switchAr = [Int] ()
    var lowSwitch = 0
    var medSwitch = 0
    var highSwitch = 0

    for _ in 1...10 {

        let switchInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(100))

        switch switchInt {

        case 0...35:
            lowSwitch = lowSwitch + 1
            switchAr.append(switchInt)
        case 36..<67:
            medSwitch = medSwitch + 1
            switchAr.append(switchInt)
        case 70..<100:
            highSwitch = highSwitch + 1
            switchAr.append(switchInt)

        default:
            print("does not compute")
        }

    }

    return(switchAr)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few basic problems with your code, it should be like so (note i've made a few changes to improve readability that do not effect the actual execution of the program).:

```
func switchInt() -> [Int] { //Short hand syntax for an array type.
    var switchAr = [Int]() //Space is unnecessary.
    var lowSwitch = 0
    var medSwitch = 0
    var highSwitch = 0

    for _ in 1...10 {

        let switchInt = Int(arc4random_uniform(100)) //NOTE: This will not include 100 it will give you a random number from 0 - 99.

        switch switchInt {

        case 0...35:
            lowSwitch += 1 //Removed return statement as you were attempting to return an int when the exepected return type is an array of Int.
            switchAr.append(switchInt)
        case 35 <= 67: //Removed reference to switchAr as that is unnecessary. 
            medSwitch +=1
            switchAr.append(switchInt)
        case 70 <= 100: //Same as above.
            highSwitch +=1 //Removed semicolon.
            switchAr.append(switchInt)

        default:
            print("does not compute")
        }

    }

    return switchAr //Removed pranas around expression following return.
}
```